# Vertical text opening HTML with MS Word

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I am writing HTML which will be later opened in MS Word. MS Word interprets my HTML and CSS just fine except one place where i have rotated text. CSS looks like this:

```
.vertical
{
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

I know it's a long shot and probably impossible, but perhaps there is a trick to make MS Word represent HTML vertical text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found solution: applying this `mso-rotate:-90` style  to `<td>` tag will make rotated text in MS Word but would not effect HTML (at least as far as I know).